# I want the menu to become a hamburger icon once it minimizes to mobile screen

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the menu a hamburger icon, 3 layers when I minimize to a mobile screen, but I am doing something wrong, and I don't know why it is not working. The icon isn't supposed to show up until after a minimize to a mobile screen. However, the icon is there, but it's just one line.

I know there is something wrong, but I just cannot pin it.

[The images attached are some guidelines to help me get through the code.]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc5U5.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwhMo.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5Uw.jpg

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("header p").click(function() {
      $("nav").toggleClass("slideDown");
    });

    $('.slick').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      fade: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2.5,
      dots: true,
    });
  });

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("header").stop().animate({
    top: $(document).scrollTop()
  }, 'slow');
});

$("#hamburger").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("change");
  $("nav").toggleClass("slideDownFurther");
}); <
/script>
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .floatRight,
  .floatLeft {
    float: none;
  }
  .slick,
  #pinkkimono {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    min-width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:641px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}

.p {
  display: none;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'agendaimport';
  src: url('../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/type/agenda_medium.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/type/agenda_medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'agenda';
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/images/BRICKSxMORTAR.jpg");
  background-size: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: floralwhite;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  color: aquamarine;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 4.5em;
  z-index: 0;
}

div {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
}

#img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: aquamarine;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -99em;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-bottom: 1em white;
  color: magenta;
  /*border-top: 1px white;
            border-bottom: 1px white;*/
  transition: margin-top 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

a.menu:link {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

a.menu:visited {
  color: rgb(6, 8, 8);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu.slideDown {
  color: magenta;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

a.menu:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#magenta {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#smaller {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  clear: both;
}

footer p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  color: magenta;
}

footer a {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  color: magenta;
}

footer p:link {
  color: black;
}

footer a:link {
  color: black;
}

.slick {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#magentaman {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.floatLeft {
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  float: right;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: +1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: +1;
}

header p {
  width: 99%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 1%;
}


/*header:hover nav{
            margin-top:-1em;
        }
    
        header.slideDown nav{
            margin-top:-1em;
        }*/

.slideDown {
  margin-top: -1em;
}

.slideDownFurther {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

header:hover p {
  color: magenta;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  animation-name: strobe;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes strobe {
  0% {
    color: floralwhite;
  }
  50% {
    color: magenta;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}

#hamburger {
  top: 0.95em;
  left: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#bar1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
}

#bar2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
}

#bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
}

.change #bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change #bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change #bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Index.html</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The homepage of Bricks and Mortar, Toronto's premiere custom clothing shop." />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="external.css">
  <script src="script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="script/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script/slick/slick.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/slick/slick-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheets" href="stylesheets/mediaqueries.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("header p").click(function() {
        $("nav").toggleClass("slideDown");
      });

      $('.slick').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2.5,
        dots: true,
      });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      $("header").stop().animate({
        top: $(document).scrollTop()
      }, 'slow');
    });

    $("#hamburger").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("change");
      $("nav").toggleClass("slideDownFurther");
    });
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <br>



  <div id="banner">

    <br>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <div id="bar1"></div>
      <div id="bar2"></div>
      <div id="bar3"></div>
    </div>

    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <p>menu</p>
      <nav>
        <a class="menu" href="OURSTORY.HTML">OUR STORY</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
        <a class="menu" href="F.A.Q.html">F.A.Q</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="mission">
      <h3 style="color:magenta">The mission of BRICKSxMORTAR is to transform how Canadians think about fashion.</h3>


      <div class="slick floatRight">
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/aqua-androgynous.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/bandmate-blouses.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/sequins-and-stones.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/roses-vest.jpg" /></div>
      </div>

      <p>For too long consumers have been forced to fit into a mould of one kind or another—assigned a size on an arbitrary scale of unrealistic and unhealthy beauty and body standards. In an over-sexualized and Photoshopped fashion market, we offer a different
        kind of clothing philosophy.

        <br>
        <br>
        <br> BRICKSxMORTAR strives to connect with the individual and to consult and create custom clothing for them with them in a collaborative manner. By doing so, our fashion studio endeavours to change consumers' perceptions of the current fashion
        landscape as well as their own views about their bodies and their fashion choices.


        <img class="floatLeft" id="magentaman" src="images/kimono-and-shorts.jpg" />


        <br> What does it feel like to wear something especially made for one's body rather than fitting one's body into a predetermined shape? We aim to answer this question a million times over as we help every client move towards a more comfortable
        version of themselves.
      </p>
      <!--end of mission-->

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <br>

      <footer>
        <h3>
          <div class="magenta"></div>
          <p>
            <div class="smaller" font-size="0.8em">

          </p>
        </h3>
        <p>©BRICKSxMORTAR, inc. 2018-2020 // 1.888.708.9950 //
          <a class="menu" href="mailto:info@bricksxmortar.com" style="color:magenta"> <u>info@bricksxmortar.com</u></a>
        </p>
      </footer>

      </div>
      <!--end of wrapper-->

</html>
</body>
```

Comment: do you want the burger to only appear on smaller screens? if it's just that, from what I've seen it's working correctly

Comment: You are inconsistent in your usage of the closing slash in `<link>`. Though allowed, no HTML specification has ever called for using a closing slash there and it has no meaning and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a media query only when the width of the page changes (minimizes).

```
#hamburger {
    display: none
}

    @media screen and (max-width:641px) {
      #hamburger {
        display: inherit;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help, I remove the unwanted jquery from your code because its shows a console error. if you want menu responsive menu then visit this [Link](https://luciferscode.blogspot.com/2021/02/simple-mobile-slide-menu.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("header p").click(function() {
        $("nav").toggleClass("slideDown");
      });

    

      $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("header").stop().animate({
          top: $(document).scrollTop()
        }, 'slow');
      });

      $("#hamburger").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("change");
        $("nav").toggleClass("slideDownFurther");
      });
    });
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width:641px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}

.p {
  display: none;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'agendaimport';
  src: url('../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/type/agenda_medium.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/type/agenda_medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'agenda';
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Demo\ Site\ Stage\ 3\ pt\ 2/images/BRICKSxMORTAR.jpg");
  background-size: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: floralwhite;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  color: aquamarine;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 4.5em;
  z-index: 0;
}

div {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
}

#img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: aquamarine;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -99em;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-bottom: 1em white;
  color: magenta;
  /*border-top: 1px white;
            border-bottom: 1px white;*/
  transition: margin-top 0.8s ease-in-out;
      position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

a.menu:link {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

a.menu:visited {
  color: rgb(6, 8, 8);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu.slideDown {
  color: magenta;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

a.menu:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#magenta {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#smaller {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  clear: both;
}

footer p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  color: magenta;
}

footer a {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  color: magenta;
}

footer p:link {
  color: black;
}

footer a:link {
  color: black;
}

.slick {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#magentaman {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.floatLeft {
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  float: right;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: +1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: +1;
}

header p {
  width: 99%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 1%;
}



.slideDown {
  margin-top: -1em;
}

.slideDownFurther {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

header:hover p {
  color: magenta;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  animation-name: strobe;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes strobe {
  0% {
    color: floralwhite;
  }
  50% {
    color: magenta;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}

#hamburger {
  top: 0.95em;
  left: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#bar1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
      margin: 5px 0;
}

#bar2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
      margin: 5px 0;
}

#bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition-property: 0.5s;
}

.change #bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.change #bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change #bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .floatRight,
  .floatLeft {
    float: none;
  }
  .slick,
  #pinkkimono {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    min-width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  div#wrapper header p {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Meta View Port -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Index.html</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The homepage of Bricks and Mortar, Toronto's premiere custom clothing shop." />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="external.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>


<body>
  <br>



  <div id="banner">

    <br>

    <div id="hamburger">
      <div id="bar1"></div>
      <div id="bar2"></div>
      <div id="bar3"></div>
    </div>

    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <p>menu</p>
      <nav>
        <a class="menu" href="OURSTORY.HTML">OUR STORY</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
        <a class="menu" href="F.A.Q.html">F.A.Q</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="mission">
      <h3 style="color:magenta">The mission of BRICKSxMORTAR is to transform how Canadians think about fashion.</h3>


      <div class="slick floatRight">
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/aqua-androgynous.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/bandmate-blouses.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/sequins-and-stones.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="slider" src="images/roses-vest.jpg" /></div>
      </div>

      <p>For too long consumers have been forced to fit into a mould of one kind or another—assigned a size on an arbitrary scale of unrealistic and unhealthy beauty and body standards. In an over-sexualized and Photoshopped fashion market, we offer a different
        kind of clothing philosophy.

        <br>
        <br>
        <br> BRICKSxMORTAR strives to connect with the individual and to consult and create custom clothing for them with them in a collaborative manner. By doing so, our fashion studio endeavours to change consumers' perceptions of the current fashion
        landscape as well as their own views about their bodies and their fashion choices.


        <img class="floatLeft" id="magentaman" src="images/kimono-and-shorts.jpg" />


        <br> What does it feel like to wear something especially made for one's body rather than fitting one's body into a predetermined shape? We aim to answer this question a million times over as we help every client move towards a more comfortable
        version of themselves.
      </p>
      <!--end of mission-->

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <br>

      <footer>
        <h3>
          <div class="magenta"></div>
          <p>
            <div class="smaller" font-size="0.8em">

          </p>
        </h3>
        <p>©BRICKSxMORTAR, inc. 2018-2020 // 1.888.708.9950 //
          <a class="menu" href="mailto:info@bricksxmortar.com" style="color:magenta"> <u>info@bricksxmortar.com</u></a>
        </p>
      </footer>

      </div>
      <!--end of wrapper-->

</html>

</body>
```